# Conditional validation with XML Schema (XSD)

Tags: xml, vba, validation, xsd, conditional-statements

I have a custom XML where some elements may be absent depending on type of parent element. Eg, if **[ATCWaypointType]** is *"Airport"*, the ***[ICAO]*** element has only one child - ***[ICAOIdent]***:

```
     <ATCWaypoint id="PAKT">
        <ATCWaypointType>Airport</ATCWaypointType>
        <WorldPosition>N55° 21' 38.88",W131° 43' 24.75",+000131.00</WorldPosition>
        <ICAO>
            <ICAOIdent>PAKT</ICAOIdent>         
        </ICAO>
    </ATCWaypoint>
```

If **[ATCWaypointType]** is *"User"*, the ***[ICAO]*** element is totally absent:

```
    <ATCWaypoint id="wpt01">
        <ATCWaypointType>User</ATCWaypointType>
        <WorldPosition>N57° 19' 35.48",W134° 8' 35.04",+000000.00</WorldPosition>
    </ATCWaypoint>
```

In all other cases ***[ICAO]*** element is represented in full:

```
    <ATCWaypoint id="SSR">
        <ATCWaypointType>VOR</ATCWaypointType>
        <WorldPosition>N58° 10' 39.60",W135° 15' 31.90",+000039.00</WorldPosition>
        <ICAO>
            <ICAORegion>PA</ICAORegion>
            <ICAOIdent>SSR</ICAOIdent>
        </ICAO>
    </ATCWaypoint>
```

Is it possible to apply some sort of conditionality using restrictions/facets to validate XML depending on type (Airport, User, etc.) of elements like in the following example with OR operator?:

```
<xs:element name="gender">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="male|female"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Here is the [XSD Schema](http://www.codeshare.io/qQkxp) I'm using.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in XSD 1.0.

In XSD 1.1 you can do it with assertions. If your ATCWayPointType were an attribute rather than an element, you could also do it (more cleanly) with conditional type assignment.

If you're stuck with 1.0 and can change the design, consider replacing the ATCWayPointType element with an xsi:type attribute that names the schema type directly.

There's also an option which people tend to forget: do a preprocessing transformation before validating. In this case your preprocessing step might add an xsi:type attribute based on the value of ATCWayPointType.